# I need to do validations for a form in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

```html
import {  FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
   ngOnInit() {
 
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }
  createFormControls(){
    
    this.firstName = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
    this.lastName= new FormControl('',Validators.required);
    this.Address= new FormControl('',Validators.required);
    this.age = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
    this.phnumer= new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  }
  createForm(){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormGroup({
      firstName:this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
      Address:this.Address,
      age:this.age,
      phnumer:this.phnumer
      }),
    });
  }
```

I need to validate a form in angular6, I have 5 fields but and need to validate without submit button, I have to validate them in same inline. this is my code in ts file now i have implement validation in html page but validation  should be shown error msg in same line instead of clicking submit button

Comment: What have you implemented so far? Your current question is Too Broad to answer. Please add some more details to it. Also, do read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am searching for validation of form without the submit button. form have to be validated, that thing I would like to know.

Comment: What have you implemented so far? Please add some sample code to work with. You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: What kind of form are you using? Reactive form or template-driven form?

Comment: i am using ReactiveForms

Comment: you can use template driven approach by using ngIf on each field you want to validate... in case the ngIf condition is true, the relevant error will be displayed and you can accompany some styling with it also

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in validators in Angular to achieve this (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)

In your component, create a form group and a getter method to access the form control through the `get` method in the parent group. I'll provide an example for a single field.

```
createForm(){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        firstName:  new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
}

get firstName() {
    return this.form.get('firstName');
}
```

In your HTML you can use conditional expressions along with the validation attributes in order to display the errors.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label for="firstName">First Name
        <input id="firstName" formControlName="firstName">
        <div *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)">
            <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
                First Name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</form>
```